# zend, how can i get data to layouts or views without assigning it everytime

Tags: zend-framework

i want to be able to get data from my controllers to be made accessible from all views or layouts..  so that i dont have to assign a variable to each controller everytime..

in my case, in my layout.phtml, theres a list of categories direct from the db, for now, i am assigning this to every controller:

```
class productsController extends Zend_Controller_Action {

    public function init() {
    Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->assign('categories',$dbArrayCategories)); 
    }
}
```

but i dont want to repeat it every time for each controller..

Comment: Where does `$dbArrayCategories` come from? Could you use the `Registry`?

Comment: Currently the Registry is kind of a IOC-Container and should not be used for data, but only for dependency objects.

Comment: dbArrayCategories is an array contianing data from my db.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a case where I would use a ViewHelper: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html. This will let you use it in any view or layout. I typically pass a model into my helper, but you can definitely have it load one up by default.

Answer (score 1):

You might extend Zend_Controller_Action with you own base class and assign the values directly in the constructor or init method.

Comment: how can i extend the Zend_Controller_Action ?

Comment: `abstract class My_Controller_Action extends Zend_Controller_Action {`

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.action.html near the end of the page